# Can't locate API module structure `config_log_module'

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, fedora-25

I have just installed `Fedora 25` on my Raspberry Pi, and I have installed Apache using the command `dnf install httpd`.

I have then enabled the service: `systemctl enable httpd.service`.

Then started the service: `service httpd start`.

This fails and when I check the log using `systemctl status httpd.service` I see the following message:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `config_log_module'
```

[EDIT]: and line 214 of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` reads:

```
LoadModule config_log_module  modules/mod_log_config.so
```

The issue being that this file does exist - so I do not understand why it is failing for this reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you paste the line 214 of your config file to make sure, but it seems you are using an incorrect module identifier.

The correct module identifier for mod_log_config is log_config_module  and not config_log_module as API the config complains about.

```
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
```

Comment: Line 214 reads: `LoadModule config_log_module  modules/mod_log_config.so`

Answer (score 0):

is there the "mod_log_config.so" file in address : "/etc/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so" ?

what is the out put of this command on your httpd server :

```
ls -l /etc/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so
```

seems this module does not exist.